# Sonar does not run phpunit in zend project

Tags: maven, zend-framework, phpunit, sonarqube

I need to run sonar on a Zend project using maven.
Everything works fine except that Sonar ignores the unit tests completely and does not run them or show their results in the report.
No errors of any kind are reported in the log.

I am using:
PHPUnit 3.6, 
Zend 1.11, 
Sonar 3.7

here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>quickstart</groupId>
 <artifactId>quickstart</artifactId>
 <name>quick start</name>
 <version>1.0</version>

 <!-- For the moment, specify pom as packaging for php projects -->
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <build>
     <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>
     <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/web</sourceDirectory>
     <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/tests</testSourceDirectory>
 </build>

 <properties>
     <sonar.projectKey>org.codehaus.sonar:quickstart</sonar.projectKey>
     <sonar.projectName>PHP project quick start</sonar.projectName>
     <sonar.projectVersion>1.0</sonar.projectVersion>
     <sonar.language>php</sonar.language>
     <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
     <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>false</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>

     <excludesAppli>**/library/**</excludesAppli>

     <sonar.exclusions>${excludesAppli}</sonar.exclusions>
     <sonar.phpCodesniffer.argumentLine>--ignore=**/library/**   </sonar.phpCodesniffer.argumentLine>
     <sonar.phpDepend.argumentLine>--ignore=**\library\**</sonar.phpDepend.argumentLine>
     <sonar.phpPmd.argumentLine>--exclude **\library\**</sonar.phpPmd.argumentLine>


     <sonar.phpUnit.coverage.analyzeOnly>false</sonar.phpUnit.coverage.analyzeOnly>
     <sonar.phpUnit.analyzeOnly>false</sonar.phpUnit.analyzeOnly>

    <sonar.phpUnit.analyze.test.directory>true</sonar.phpUnit.analyze.test.directory>
    <sonar.phpUnit.skip>false</sonar.phpUnit.skip>
    <sonar.phpUnit.coverage.skip>false</sonar.phpUnit.coverage.skip>
    <!--<sonar.phpUnit.mainTestClass></sonar.phpUnit.mainTestClass> -->
    <!--<sonar.phpUnit.configuration>${basedir}/tests/phpunit.xml</sonar.phpUnit.configuration> -->
 </properties>
```

any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved I need to edit:

```
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>false</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
```

to

```
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>true</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
```